# C++ Socket select() before accept() seeing same connection multiple times

Tags: c++, sockets

I have a listen function that checks if a new connection is waiting on the server socket, if I start the client first and then start the server I am seeing the 'new connection' multiple times, where if I start the server and then the client I see it once.

Am I missing some knowledge of the Posix standard or just lacking knowledge (most likely)?

The function to poll for a new connection is:

```
bool IPV4Socket::HasNewConnection( TimeoutValue *timeout )
{
    SocketSet read_fd_set;
    bool hasConnection = false;

    SocketSet_ZERO( &read_fd_set );
    SocketSet_SET( m_socket, &read_fd_set );

    if ( m_socketAdaptor->select( m_socket + 1
                                , &read_fd_set
                                , NULL
                                , NULL
                                , timeout ) < 0 )
    {
        throw( std::string( "::select() failed, unable to continue." ) );
    }

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i <= m_socket; i++ )
    {
        if ( m_socketAdaptor->SocketSet_ISSET( i, &read_fd_set ) &&
             ( i == m_socket ) )
        {
            hasConnection = true;
        }
    }

    return hasConnection;
}
```

It is called using:

```
while( 1 )
{
    if ( socket->HasNewConnection( &newConnTimeout ) )
    {
        std::cout << "[INFO] A new connection is waiting...." << std::endl;

        acceptedSocket = socket->Accept( &newConnTimeout );

        if ( acceptedSocket )
        {
            std::cout << "[INFO] New connection received...." << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

The connect functionality is:

```
while( connStatus == false )
{
    socket = socketlayer->CreateSocket( socketlayer::SockType_stream );

    socket->SetNonBlocking( true );
    socket->SetSocketOption( socketlayer::SocketOption_KeepAlive, true );
    socket->SetSocketOption( socketlayer::SocketOption_ReuseAddr, true );

    connStatus = socket->Connect( "127.0.0.1", 18000, &tv );

    if ( connStatus == false ) socket->Close();
}
```

As this is an open source piece of code, which can be found in [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/p/libssl/code/ci/default/tree/)

Connect is done via:

```
bool IPV4Socket::Connect( std::string hostname
                        , unsigned short remotePort
                        , TimeoutValue *timeout )
{
    AddrInfo getResults;
    AddrInfo getaddrinfoHints;
    int connReturn = 0;
    SockAddr_In *addrData;
    //bool connectSuccess = false;
    std::string service = std::to_string( remotePort );

    getaddrinfoHints.ai_family = AddressFamily_inet;
    getaddrinfoHints.ai_socktype = SockType_stream;

    if ( m_socketAdaptor->getaddrinfo( hostname
                                     , service
                                     , &getaddrinfoHints
                                     , &getResults ) != 0 )
    {
        return false;
    }

    addrData = (SockAddr_In *)&( *getResults.ai_addr.begin() );

    connReturn = m_socketAdaptor->connect( m_socket
                                         , (const Sockaddr *)addrData
                                         , (int)getResults.ai_addrlen );

    if ( connReturn == SocketError)
    {
        int m_lastErrorCode = m_socketAdaptor->GetLastError();

        //  Connection error : FATAL 
        if ( ( m_lastErrorCode != SockErr_EWOULDBLOCK) &&
             ( m_lastErrorCode != SockErr_EALREADY ) && 
             ( m_lastErrorCode != SockErr_EINPROGRESS ) )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    SocketSet writeFDS;
    //SocketSet exceptFDS;
    int selectReturn = 0;

    //  Clear all the socket FDS structures
    SocketSet_ZERO( &writeFDS );
    //SocketSet_ZERO( &exceptFDS );

    //  Put the socket into the FDS structures
    SocketSet_SET( m_socket, &writeFDS );
    //SocketSet_SET( m_socket, &exceptFDS );

    selectReturn = m_socketAdaptor->select( m_socket + 1
                                            , NULL
                                            , &writeFDS
                                            , NULL
                                            , timeout );

    //  Check for Socket Error or timeout
    if ( ( selectReturn == SocketError ) || ( selectReturn == 0 ) )
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: What's the client connection code? Perhaps it tries to reconnect.

Comment: What does the `Accept()` method look like? And why does it have a timeout parameter?

Comment: @EJP I don't want the accept to block.  Accept() is just a wrapper for ::accept() => newSocket = ::accept( m_socket, (sockaddr *)addr, addrlen );

Comment: @Kenney The client retries until the connection was success.

Comment: Then that is why there are multiple connections waiting. You're probably not cancelling the connect properly, keeping it pending at the server. But it's hard to say without seeing the client code.

Comment: @Kenney I have updated question with connect info.

Comment: Why do you close the socket after you start connecting it?

Comment: Your HasNewConnection() should handle timeout properly, there's no telling what's in your `read_fd_set` if you reach a timeout. If your `socket->Accept` is a simple wrapper around accep(),`if ( acceptedSocket )` will be true if it returns -1 too.

Comment: I repeat. Why does `Accept()` have a timeout parameter? You aren't using it, and you *can't* use it without doing another `select().`

Comment: @EJP IPV4Socket::Accept has timeout as it does ' if ( m_socketAdaptor->select( SocketSetSize, &set, 0, &set, timeout ) > 0 )' - Is select in the wrong place

Comment: @PaulMorriss: Yes, because `HasNewConnection()` has already called `select()` beforehand.  If `select()` reports a connection is waiting, `accept()` will not block, there is no point in calling `select()` a second time since it will never timeout.  If you are going to call `select()` inside of `m_socketAdapter->Accept()` then `HasNewConnection()` becomes useless and should be removed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you, light bulb has finally turned on :)

Comment: I asked you to post the code of the `Accept()` method. You posted it in a comment, which is the wrong place, and the code you posted did not contain a `select()`, *ergo* the timeout parameter was pointless. And if your `Accept()` method does perform a `select()`, contrary to your explicit statement above that it is just a wrapper for `::accept(),` it is redundant, as you have already done one, so the timeout parameter is *still* pointless.

Comment: @EJP Sorry, it shouldn't have been in the comment.  I have remove the call to HasNewConnection() and relying on select() against read set now.  Unfortunately it's still generating the extra 'accepts'

Answer (score 1):

The socket is set up to be non-blocking, and a call to [connect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will typically return an error because the connection status can't be determined yet:

> With a nonblocking socket, the connection attempt cannot be completed immediately. In this case, connect will return SOCKET_ERROR, and WSAGetLastError will return WSAEWOULDBLOCK. (...)
>
> - Use the select function to determine the completion of the connection request by checking to see if the socket is writeable.

Given your client code and the above documentation, it should never be able to successfully connect. However, since you connect using the loopback device, in the case where your server is already running it can (and does) happen that the connection is immediately accepted due to timing.

So either use `select` on the client after the `connect` call as outlined above or simply use a blocking socket.

Comment: And if the OP is on a posix system, it'll be similar but `connect()` returns -1 and sets `errno` to  `EINPROGRESS`

Comment: In Connect() itself I do a select - https://sourceforge.net/p/libssl/code/ci/default/tree/src/IPV4Socket.cpp

Comment: Looks good. You are seeing "[INFO] A new connection is waiting...." multiple times - are you also seeing "[INFO] New connection received...." multiple times?

Comment: @Kenney Yes, that is exactly what I am seeing, I added a count and for 1 connection HasNewConnection() returned 'connection waiting' 11 times..

Comment: @PaulMorriss: Please show the actual code for `Accept()`. You can't get 11 `connection is waiting` messages unless `Accept()` is not actually accepting them correctly, so they stay in the queue.

Answer (score 1):

`HasNewConnection()` is ignoring when `select()` times out, and its loop is completely redundant since it is waiting on only one socket at a time.  The code can be simplified to the following:

```
bool IPV4Socket::HasNewConnection( TimeoutValue *timeout )
{
    SocketSet read_fd_set;

    SocketSet_ZERO( &read_fd_set );
    SocketSet_SET( m_socket, &read_fd_set );

    int ret = m_socketAdaptor->select( m_socket + 1
                                , &read_fd_set
                                , NULL
                                , NULL
                                , timeout );
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        throw( std::string( "::select() failed, unable to continue." ) );
    }

    return (ret > 0);
}
```

With that said, I just looked at the code for `Accept()` (please don't ask people to look at code an external site, please always put it in your actual question, where it belongs) and I see one big mistake in it.  You are using the same `SocketSet` variable for two different parameters of `select()`, so the content of that variable will be undefined when `select()` exits.  If you want to check the `read/write` and `except` parameters together, you need to use separate variables (like you do in `Connect()`):

```
iSocket *IPV4Socket::Accept( TimeoutValue *timeout )
{
    SocketSet readFDS;
    SocketSet exceptFDS;
    Socket newSocketHandle = 0;

    //  Clear all the socket FDS structures
    SocketSet_ZERO( &readFDS );
    SocketSet_ZERO( &exceptFDS );

    //  Add listening socket to the FDS structures
    SocketSet_SET( m_socket, &readFDS );
    SocketSet_SET( m_socket, &exceptFDS );

    if ( m_socketAdaptor->select( m_socket + 1, &readFDS, NULL, &exceptFDS, timeout ) > 0 )
    {
        if ( !m_socketAdaptor->SocketSet_ISSET( m_socket, &exceptFDS ) )
        {
            newSocketHandle = m_socketAdaptor->accept( m_socket, NULL, NULL );

            if ( newSocketHandle != Invalid_Socket )
            {
                return new IPV4Socket( newSocketHandle, m_socketType, m_socketAdaptor );
            }
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

However, this is fairly redundant for `accept()`, you don't need to use the `except` parameter at all (it makes sense for `connect()` but not `accept()`):

```
iSocket *IPV4Socket::Accept( TimeoutValue *timeout )
{
    SocketSet readFDS;
    Socket newSocketHandle = 0;

    //  Clear the socket FDS structure
    SocketSet_ZERO( &readFDS );

    //  Add listening socket to the FDS structure
    SocketSet_SET( m_socket, &readFDS );

    if ( m_socketAdaptor->select( m_socket + 1, &readFDS, NULL, NULL, timeout ) > 0 )
    {
        newSocketHandle = m_socketAdaptor->accept( m_socket, NULL, NULL );

        if ( newSocketHandle != Invalid_Socket )
        {
            return new IPV4Socket( newSocketHandle, m_socketType, m_socketAdaptor );
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Firstly, apologies for faux par, being open source I thought it would be easier to show whole thing for context.   I have changed Accept as per above and removed call to HasNewConnection and I am still seeing 11+ 'A new connection has been received'?

Comment: Well, then you really are accepting 11 connections since `Accept()` cannot return an invalid connection.  That goes back to the earlier comments that maybe the client is reconnecting incorrectly and not closing old connections, so they stay in the server's queue for `accept()` to return. Another way to handle that is if `Accept()` returns a new connection then immediately perform a non-blocking read on it, and if it fails or returns 0 then the client already disconnected before it was removed from the queue, so just close and ignore it.

Comment: if Connect() returns fail it does a if ( connStatus == false ) socket->Close();

Comment: @PaulMorriss: that does not guarantee that `Connect()` is reporting failure correctly, or that `Close()` is closing the socket correctly.

Comment: I have added the connect function.  Any additional advise would be welcomed and listened to as I am confused.

Comment: I am fully closing the socket on failed ::connect(), if the server isn't up, can they still be added to the accept queue??